# What's Wrong With my Page?

Tags: die2nite

[image: aSidebars]

What's up with those scrollbars?  This isn't the first time this has happened.

For clarification, the issue here is that the horizontal and vertical scrollbars are about an inch thicker than they are supposed to be.

It was like this for about a week, a week or two ago, and then it just went back to normal.   It's doing it again now.

I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an intermittent issue with Chrome where this happens. I haven't been able to determine what the cause is, but unmaximizing the browser window, and then maximizing it again seems to clear up the problem.